# ListView not Appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to make an activity that provides a list of emergency phone numbers with the ability for the user to add their own custom entries and save them. For some reason, the ListView doesn't appear on the activity. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in the CustomAdapter class that I made to hold two text boxes in each segment of the ListView.

I'm also trying to set the listView to start a phone activity with the phone number of whatever segment was touched, and I'm unsure if I'm doing this correctly.

PhoneList.java :

```
public class PhoneList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> customList;
    ArrayList<String> numList;
    Bundle b;
    TinyDB tinydb;
    CustomAdapter dataAdapter;
    ListView phoneListView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_list);
        phoneListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPhone);
        Integer num = null;
        String label = "";
        customList = null;
        numList = null;
        tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
        Button saveContact = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.button4));

        b = new Bundle();


        customList = tinydb.getListString("label");
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = tinydb.getListInt("num");
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            numList.add(temp.get(i).toString());
        }


        saveContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText enteredLabel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText enteredNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                String label = enteredLabel.getText().toString();
                Integer num = Integer.parseInt(enteredNum.getText().toString());
                b.putString("label",label);
                b.putInt("num",num);
                addPhoneItem();


            }
        });


        ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add("Emergencies");
        phoneList.add("Travel Info ");
        phoneList.add("Poison Control ");
        phoneList.add("AAA: 1(800)836-2582");
        if(customList != null && customList.size() > 0) phoneList.addAll(customList);

        ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
        numberList.add("911");
        numberList.add("511");
        numberList.add("18002221222");
        numberList.add("18008362582");
        if(numList != null && numList.size()>0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numList.size(); i++) {
                numberList.add(numList.get(i).toString());
            }
        }



        dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,numberList,phoneList);
        phoneListView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }
    public void addPhoneItem(){
        customList.add(b.getString("label"));
        numList.add(b.getString("num"));
        tinydb.putListString("label",customList);
        tinydb.putListString("num",numList);
        dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,numList,customList);
        phoneListView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        ArrayList<String> labels;
        ArrayList<String> nums;
        Context context;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> n,ArrayList<String> l) {
            super(context,R.layout.phone_item);
            this.context = context;
            labels = new ArrayList<String>();
            labels.addAll(l);
            nums = new ArrayList<String>();
            nums.addAll(n);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            try {
                ViewHolder holder = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.phone_item, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.viewLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    holder.viewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);


                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                String label = labels.get(position);
                String num = nums.get(position);
                holder.viewLabel.setText(label);
                holder.viewNumber.setText(num);
                holder.viewNumber.setTag(num);
                holder.viewNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String str = "tel:" + (EditText) v.getTag();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(str));
                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Exception Caught in CustomAdapter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });



            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Exception caught",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return convertView;

        }

    }
    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView viewLabel;
        TextView viewNumber;
    }
}
```

activity_phone_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res``/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rvtripapp.dempsey.rvtripapp.PhoneList">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/listViewPhone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:hint="Label" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Phone Number" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:background="#44fe66"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

phone_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Firstly check `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res\`\`/android"`. You have backticks in there. Secondly, make your ListView a crazy colour like `android:background="#ff9900"` to check it really is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Change the super keyword line to

```
    super(context,R.layout.phone_item, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override the getCount method of the CustomAdapter class ?

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return labels.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your custom adapter outside onCreate() try to set it inside the onCreate().